# Curl upload file with metadata

Tags: curl, sharepoint, metadata

I'm trying to use cURL to upload a file along with some metadata to a SharePoint site, but so far have been unable to. The command is able to upload the file, but it does not populate the metadata. For testing purposes, I'm trying to populate the "Title" metadata field with "TEST1". Eventually, I'll have multiple metadata fields I want to populate per file. Below is my command:

```
curl.exe -H 'Content-type:text:json' -d '{"Title":"TEST1"}' --ntlm -fail --max-time 120 --user username:password --upload-file test.pdf http://website/test.pdf
```